# Defining List of Enum as DTO Class C#

Tags: c#, class, dto

This is my input JSON response

```
{
   "permissions": {
            "user": [
                "Add",
                "Update",
                "Delete"
            ],
            "Product": [
                "Read",
                "Create"
            ]
        }
}
```

I'm trying to create the DTO class for the same. So far I've created a set of Enum with the available values

**PermissionAction Enum**

```
 public enum PermissionAction
    {
        Add,
        Update,
        Read,
        Delete,
        Create
    }
```

**PermissionItem Enum**

```
public enum PermissionItem
{
    User,
    Product
}
```

How to create a DTO Class for the given JSON Response with the available Enums?

I tired like differently like

```
public class Permissions
{

    public List<PermissionAction> User { get; set; }

    public List<PermissionItem> Product { get; set; }
}
```

Which is wrong.

Since the response may vary dynamically. What I mean that is sometimes a `User` List will not available and sometimes `Product` is not available.

Like,

```
{
   "permissions": {
            "user": [
                "Add",
                "Update",
                "Delete"
            ]
      }
}
```

I need to support those kinds of response also with my DTO Class.

UPDATE 1:

*I think the JSON which I posted above is confusing others. Sorry for that confusion. Actually, my permissions JSON Object is contained List of Permission Item(s) in which each Permission Items itself again having a List of Permission Actions.*

Comment: why PermissionItem contains User, Product? It must be "Read",          "Create"?

Comment: @ThierryV please see my update 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need to use binary or (i.e. `|`) customizing the serialization.

`Enum` can already parse many names:

```
[Flags] // <--- Don't forget to apply this attribute if you want masks!
public enum A { X, Y }

Enum.TryParse<A>("X, Y", out var flags);

if(flags.HasFlag(A.X) && flags.HasFlag(A.Y))
{
    // It'll enter here!
}
```

Definitively, you need to customize your deserialization so that *flags* coming as *arrays* get turned into a comma-separated capitalized flag string.

That is, you'll end up with this class:

```
public class Permissions
{
    public Permissions(A a, B b) 
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }

    public A A { get; }
    public B B { get; }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly, I couldn't understand the logic? Sorry about that. Enum.TryParse<A>("X,Y") here what are the X and Y string referring to?
Also, it would be great helpful if you give the explanation with my Enum's instead of A ,B X,Y.

Comment: @Jayendran It's exactly the same with any `Enum`. You're looking for converting the JSON arrays into a bit mask

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Newtosoft.Json that you get from NuGet:

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
   ""permissions"": {
            ""user"": [
                ""Add"",
                ""Update"",
                ""Delete""
            ],
            ""Product"": [
                ""Read"",
                ""Create""
            ]
        }
}";

    var root = Root.FromJson(json);

    Console.WriteLine("C# Object");
    Console.WriteLine("Permissions:");
    Console.WriteLine("\tUser:[");
    foreach (var v in root.Permissions.User)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{v}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\t]");
    Console.WriteLine("\tProduct:[");
    foreach (var v in root.Permissions.Product)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t\t{v}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\t]");


    Console.WriteLine("As JSON string");
    Console.WriteLine(root.ToJson());
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum UserAction { 
    Add,
    Update,
    Delete
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public enum ProductAction
{
    Read,
    Create
}

public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("permissions")]
    public Permissions Permissions { get; set; }

    public static Root FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
    public string ToJson() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
}

public class Permissions
{
    [JsonProperty("user")]
    public List<UserAction> User { get; set ; }

    [JsonProperty("Product")]
    public List<ProductAction> Product { get; set; }
}
```